# Should business property tax return item values include shipping and sales tax?

Tags: united-states, taxes, property-taxes

When filing [a business property tax return](http://www.lynchburgva.gov/sites/default/files/COLFILES/Commissioner-Revenue/2015%20BPP%20Form.pdf) in Virginia (USA), should the amounts on the return and itemized list that goes along with it include the shipping and sales tax costs of the equipment and furniture?

For example, let's say I buy a computer for:

```
Subtotal: $1,000 
S&H: $50 
Tax: $60 
Total: $1,110
```

What number should I put on the tax return, and what number should I put on the itemized list?

Thanks!

Comment: Please specify your country and the specific tax form to which you are referring.

Comment: @dg99 Sorry, I should have included that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, it could vary by city, but typically original cost basis includes tax, delivery, and installation. So in your case it would be the full $1110.

Here are links to a couple references in your state:

http://www.manassascity.org/index.aspx?NID=124

http://www.albemarle.org/department.asp?department=finance&relpage=3279